Fetching git commit details in jenkins pipeline
I've configured a Jenkins pipeline to fetch commit author and commit message details. However, when commits are made through the GitHub UI, I'm only getting 'GITHUB' as the username instead of the actual commit details. How can I ensure that I get the correct commit details regardless of whether the commit is made via the CLI or the GitHub UI?
Below is the slack notification details get when it is being commited in the ui.
The dev - service main deploy succeeded.
CommitId: xxxxx
Commit Message: Merge pull request #567 from xxxx branch
Commit User:GitHub
Build URL:https://xxx/.com

What sends this slack message? Plugin? Custom code? What's the source of the user name?
